# Blueprint nested containers

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I am having a Fluid Grid System container nested into another container.

```
<div class="fluid_grid_layout">
    <div class="six_column section">
        <div class="three column">
            <div class="six_column section">
                <div class="two column">part</div>
                <div class="four column">part</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="three column">boko</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How this can be achieved using Blueprint 1.0?
Is it posible to have one container inside another which allows you finer(more granular control) of the nested content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparently this is not possible in Blueprint. I ended up using Fluid Grid System from http://fluid.newgoldleaf.com/.